# Node.js app not connect to docker redis container

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

[I connected with docker redis container.The redis working in the docker.If I execute the docker file with `docker exec -it 96e199a8badf sh`, I connected to redis server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWlcN.png)

[My node.js application like this.I use redis 4.1.0 version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmsaf.png)

I don't know, what's going on.How can I fix this?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: delivery-app
    build:
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app,
      - '/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - redis
networks:
  redis:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node","server.js"]
```

code:

```
 const redisClient = redis.createClient({
            socket: {
                port: 6379,
                host: "redis"
            }
        });
        await redisClient.connect();
        redisClient.on('connect',function(){
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            })
        }).on('error',function(error){
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false
            })
        });
```

package.json

```
"redis": "^4.1.0"
```

Comment: [please dont post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9583747)

Comment: is the redis container running? can you connect to it with the [cli](https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/#host-port-password-and-database)?

Comment: I am connecting with redis-cli.

Comment: `code` $ docker exec -it 96e199a8badf sh
# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> PING
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379>

Comment: have you tried removing the `host: redis` allowing to try the default of `localhost`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It's not working.

Comment: I would try using their [basic usage](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example) example to get a 'Hello World' sanity check

Comment: I tried this basic usage. But this is not working. I think that problem is redis version.Can you tell me which version you are using?

Comment: if redis is correctly running, you should be able to just simply pass in the url to createClient like so: `createClient({url: `redis://172.17.0.1:6379`});`

Comment: If this doesnt work then I would go back to that redis is not setup correctly through docker, can you show the command you used to build/run the container?

Comment: version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: delivery-app
    build:
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app,
      - '/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    networks:
      - redis
networks:
  redis:
    driver: bridge
    
    // With this docker-compose.yml file, I run docker-compose up command

Comment: you are exposing port 3000 on the container while trying to connect to port 6376. Update the ports you are exposing and you should be good

Comment: I added port 6376 to redis image. I tested again. This is not working

Comment: Sorry, i hit a typo, but you should be using the port number you are passing into the socket object. 6379

Comment: I wrote like this. socket: {
                port: 6379,
                host: "redis"
            } This is not working.

Comment: but did you update your docker compose to use that port instead of 3000 or 6376?

Comment: like this?  version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: delivery-app
    build:
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app,
      - '/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - redis
networks:
  redis:
    driver: bridge

Comment: When I write like this, I send request in postman. But request doesn't response.After a few minutes, I encounter etimeout error.

Comment: try and connect via the cli, on your machine not through the redis container

Comment: $ ping 127.0.0.1:6379
Ping request could not find host 127.0.0.1:6379. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: ok, so this means the container is not updated correctly, could you update the question with your docker compose file so I can see the formatting better? It is hard to read it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by passing the host parameter as a socket object in createClient like this

```
{ 
  socket: {
    host: "redis"
  }
}
```

This seems to be new because before you didn't have to use the socket object

Here's the documentation for node-redis createClient

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/client-configuration.md

Comment: I write like this.But this is not working ```                                                                            const redisClient = redis.createClient({
            socket: {
                host: "redis"
            }
        });
        await redisClient.connect();
        redisClient.on('connect',function(){
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            })
        }).on('error',function(error){
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false
            })
        });    ```

Comment: In the image posted, OP is passing `redis` into the socket object