# Docker - Redis connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, docker, express, redis

I know this is a common error, but I literally spent the entire day trying to get past this error, trying everything I could find online. But I cant find anything that works for me.

I am very new to Docker and using it for my NodeJS + Express + Postgresql + Redis application.

Here is what I have for my docker-compose file:

```js
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
  cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
    #  target: production
    # image: api
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_NAME: postgres
      REDIS_HOST: cache
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
    links:
      - db
      - cache
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
  cache:
    driver: local
```

Here is my app.js upper part:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const redis = require('redis')

const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'cache',
  port: 6379,
  legacyMode: true // Also tried without this line, same behavior
})

client.connect()
client.on('connect', () => {
  log('Redis connected')
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
```

And my Dockerfile:

```js
FROM node:16.15-alpine3.14
WORKDIR ./
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 3000 6379

CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

npm run serve is `nodemon ./app.js`.

I also already tried to prune the system and network.

What am I missing? Help!

Comment: Can you connect to redis using the CLI on your host?

Comment: Do you need to add a `socket: {}` wrapper to the parameters in `redis.createClient()`?  (For example, [Node.js app not connect to docker redis container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162790/node-js-app-not-connect-to-docker-redis-container/72162865#72162865).)

Answer (score -1):

There are two things to put in mind here,

First of All **Docker Network**:
Containers are exposed to your localhost system, so as a "Server" you can access each of them directly through the browser or the command-line, **But**

1. Taken for granted that you only can access the containers because they are exposed to a default network that is accessible by the root of the system - the docker user *which you can inspect by the way*.
2. The deployed containers are not exposed to each other by default, so you need to define a virtual network and expose them to it so they can talk to each other through the ports or the host name -- which will be the `container_name`

So you need to do two things:

1. Add a container name to the redis, in the compose file just like you did on the API
2. Create a network and bind all the services to it, one way of doing that will be:

```html
version: "3.8"
    Network: 
      my-network:
        name: my-network
    services:
    ....
    
    cache:
      container_name: cache
      image: redis:6.2-alpine
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
      volumes:
        - cache:/data
      networks: # add it in all containers that communicate together
        - my-network
```

Then and only then you can call redis container name as the host, since docker network will create a host name for the service by the container name,
When deploying the whole compose file later, the containers will be created and all will be joined to the network by default on startup and that will allow you API app to communicate with Redis container via the docker container name as the host name

Refer to these resources for more details:

- [Networking on Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)
- [Docker Network Overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

**A side Unrelated note:**
I personally used redis from npm for some testing projects, but I found that ioredis was much better with TypeScript projects and more expected in its behavior

To Avoid any problems with Redis, make sure to create a password and use it to connect, sometimes redis randomly considers the client as a `ReadOnly` client and fails to find a read replica, adding the password solved it for me

Comment: You need to do neither of the specific things you mention; see the _Networking in Compose_ link.  Compose creates a network named `default` so you don't need to manually declare one, and each container is visible on that network using its Compose service name (the `db`, `cache`, `api` keys under `services:`) so you do not need `container_name:`.